# FileNET P8 5.2.1 FP2 - edit permissions on document creation

Tags: java, filenet-p8, filenet-content-engine

We're asked to set up permissions when a document is created.

Basically the code part written is reproduced below :

```
public void onEvent(ObjectChangeEvent event, Id eventId) {
    if (event instanceof CreationEvent) {
        Document doc = (Document) event.get_SourceObject();
        AccessPermissionList permissions = doc.get_Permissions();
        String creatorGranteeName = getCreatorGranteeName(doc);
        Iterator<AccessPermission> iter = permissions.iterator();
        boolean found = false;
        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            AccessPermission ace = (AccessPermission) iter.next();
            if (ace.get_GranteeName().equals(creatorGranteeName)) {
                permissions.remove(ace);
                // relevant ? is "permission" duplicated ?
                doc.set_Permissions(permissions);
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!found) return ; // no need to save
        doc.save(RefreshMode.REFRESH); // --> triggers CreationEvent -> loop
        System.out.println("Saved."); // never reached
    }
}
```

I tried two ways : a preprocessor or a subscription.

**Preprocessor** doesn't work since the document doesn't seems to be fully built, especially about permissions (only administrators are set). Fetching doesn't seem to work (which is understandable, since the document isn't yet stored).

**Susbcription** crashes if it's *synchronously* processed at `doc.save()` line, regardless if the refresh mode is `RefreshMode.REFRESH` or `RefreshMode.NO_REFRESH`.
If it's *asynchrounsly* done, it seems to loop, as if `doc.save` retriggers a `CreationEvent`.

So I'm looking for a help if I did something wrong, or for a third way if it exists.

EDIT : added block code which skips saving if no permissions to remove was found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said by @Manjunatha Muniyappa, I solved my problem by fetching the document from the Object store rather than getting it from the CreationEvent object. [It seems to be recommended by the editor](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/filenet-p8-platform/5.2.0?topic=subscriptions-working#subscription_procedures__creating_eventhandler) (*"as a best practice, fetch the persisted source object of the event"*). Also by this way the CreationEvent won't be raised (I dunno why).

So the solution is to create an **asynchronous subscription** on Creation Event, associated with this handler class below :

```
// Only relevant lines are kept.
public class CustomEventAction implements EventActionHandler {
    // [...]
    public void onEvent(ObjectChangeEvent event, Id eventId) {
        if (event instanceof CreationEvent) {
            ObjectStore os = event.getObjectStore();
            Id id = event.get_SourceObjectId();
            FilterElement fe = 
                    new FilterElement(null, null, null, "permissions creator", null);
            PropertyFilter pf = new PropertyFilter();
            pf.addIncludeProperty(fe);
            Document doc = Factory.Document.fetchInstance(os, id, pf);
            
            AccessPermissionList permissions;
        
            String creatorGranteeName = getCreatorGranteeName(doc);
            permissions = doc.get_Permissions();
            Iterator<AccessPermission> iter = permissions.iterator();
            
            boolean found = false;
            while (iter.hasNext()) {
                AccessPermission ace = (AccessPermission) iter.next();
                if (ace.get_GranteeName().equals(creatorGranteeName)) {
                    permissions.remove(ace);
                    found = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            
            if (!found) {
                return;
            }
            
            doc.save(RefreshMode.REFRESH);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since I can't comment because of reputation, I have to answer it
Did you try

```
doc.checkin(AutoClassify.DO_NOT_AUTO_CLASSIFY, CheckinType.MAJOR_VERSION);
```

before `doc.save()`

Updated answer

Also instead of `event.get_SourceObject();` can you try like

```
changeEvent.get_SourceObjectId(); 
Document doc= Factory.Document.fetchInstance(os, documentId, propertyFilter);
```

Comment: I didn't, but what's the purpose ? Does this prevent to raise again a `CreationEvent` ? Also it seems that it will create a new version (I guess a checkOut will be required).

Comment: Your code is saving the document before check-in so if you check-in and the save would solve the problem. Also instead of event.get_SourceObject(); can you try like changeEvent.get_SourceObjectId();                                         Document doc= Factory.Document.fetchInstance(os, documentId, propertyFilter);

Comment: Also please remove the part concerning `checkin()`  call, it was not relevant in this context. I updvoted you because you mentionned the `Document.fetchInstance()` call, as did our expert right before, and selected mine designed after our expert's answer since it's more complete/accurate.